# Iterate through map with tuple

Tags: c++, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to iterate through a map, that has a tuple. The below fails

```
std::map<int, std::tuple<int,       double, double, double>> database;

for (auto d : database){  
        if (std::get<3>(d) > temp){
            json tmp;
            tmp = { 
            { "result", "ok" },
            { "id", id },
            { "timestamp", std::get<0>(d) },
            { "x", std::get<1>(d) },
            { "y", std::get<2>(d) },
            { "temperature", std::get<3>(d) } 
            };
            result+=tmp;
        }
        id++;
}
```

The error message is massive, this is the first part

```
temperature_server.cc:83:30: error: no matching function for call to 'get(std::pair<const int, std::tuple<int, double, double, double> >&)'
         if (std::get<3>(d) > temp){
```

Comment: `d` is a `std::pair<int, std::tuple<int, double, double, double>>` ... `d.first` is the key and `d.second` is the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
for (const auto& p : database){
    const auto& d = p.second; // std::tuple<int, double, double, double>
    // ...
```